# Quadratic Equation by Factoring

Tags: quadratics

My son has this problem on his homework and I can't figure out the process to solve this equation. The instructions say "Solve each equation by factoring". Can someone help and please show steps?

(7b+1)(7b-5) = 0

Comment: The equality holds if and only if either $7b+1=0$ or $7b-5=0$.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @user236182, please consider posting your comment as an answer so that the OP could accept it. It should have been an answer in the first place anyway. Otherwise someone else will do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an equation is written as a product of several factors equal to zero, it means that any of these factors can be equal to zero and the equation is satisfied. In this case, we have

$7b+1 = 0$, which leads to $b = -1/7$

or

$7b-5=0$, which yields $b = 5/7$.

Hope this helps.